# How to allocate space on active partition to install windows?

Tags: disk-usage

when i try to unmount or add partition it does not let me do it. The information describes the partition is active. How do i do it? I am planning to seperate 100gb for windows

Comment: You can not do what you are trying to do. Boot from live media and run gparted.

Comment: Oh sorry for that, I would appreciate  if you add some more details in question , so that I can know exactly the problem, like what you tried , what research did you did and more.

Comment: Well I have 240gb SSD. I have 2 partitions i.e. /dev/sda1 (512 MB) and /dev/sda2(223 GB). Now i want to take 100GB out of sda2 and make new something like sda3 where i can install windows. But when I try to unmount or create partition it either says traget is busy or it is active. Now how should i do it I am trying to dual boot

Comment: You cannot shrink sda2 while the system is running - it’s where the system is stored! @David is correct. You need to boot a live environment and use gparted from there. Installing Windows after Ubuntu is not trivial. Research how to do it and get hold of some system rescue tools before you start. In fact the first thing you should do is make a system backup so you can reset things if it goes wrong

Comment: I already gave you the answer the very fist comment.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, while most operating systems allow the user to allocate the specific location in which to install the operating system (often even giving control over the boot and OS partitions), **Windows installer does not have this capability**. There are some workarounds, but they are difficult, and are not recommended. If you are trying to dual boot you will be better off installing Windows first, then installing your second OS second.